# Multiplicate two line from the same column

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to multiplcate 2 results in the same column with the help of another column. I'll try to explain:

First, let me introduce the tables I use:

### 1/ Search products (object ID) of a term referent (term_taxonomy id)

TAB => wp_term_relationships

```
+-----------+------------------+
| object_id | term_taxonomy_id |
+-----------+------------------+
| 723       | 685              |
| 724       | 685              |
+--------------+---------------+
```

### 2/ Search all products ID (meta_value) of the _product_id(meta_key) to get the order_item_id of each

TAB => wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
NB: The meta_id 400 not belong of the term referent

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+
| meta_id | order_item_id |  meta_key     | meta_value |
+-------- +---------------+---------------+------------+
| 203     | 24            | _product_id   | 723        |
| 204     | 24            | _product_cost | 79         |
| 205     | 24            | _qty          | 5          |
| 355     | 56            | _product_id   | 724        |
| 356     | 56            | _product_cost | 99         |
| 357     | 56            | _qty          | 3          |
| 400     | 26            | _product_id   | 1500       |
+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

### 3/ Search all order_ID (meta_value) to get the order_id

TAB => wp_woocommerce_order_items
NB: The order_item_id 26 not belong of the term referent
NB2: two products in order_id 10 (1&3)

```
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+
| order_item_id | order_item_name |  order_item_type | order_id |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+
| 24            | product 1       | line_item        | 10       |
| 25            | delivery        | shipping         | 10       |
| 56            | product 3       | line_item        | 10       |
| 26            | product 50      | line_item        | 11       |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+
```

### 4/ Search all order_id (ID) and pass arguments WHERE to filter the list

TAB => wp_posts

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
| ID | post_status  |  post_date          |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 10 | wc-completed | 2018-09-25 23:04:52 |
| 11 | wc-suspend   | 2017-09-25 23:04:52 |
| 15 | wc-completed | 2017-09-66 23:04:52 |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Now, following what I've done so far:

```
SELECT
COUNT( posts.ID ) AS count_orders,
SUM(order_meta_items_cost.meta_value * order_meta_items_qty.meta_value) AS total_sales

FROM wp_posts AS posts

LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = '685'

LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_meta_items 
ON order_meta_items.meta_value = rel.object_id 
AND order_meta_items.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'

LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS order_items 
ON order_items.order_item_id = order_meta_items.order_item_id 
AND order_items.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'

INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS order_items_cost 
ON order_items_cost.order_id = posts.ID 
AND order_items.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'

INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_meta_items_cost 
ON order_meta_items_cost.order_item_id = order_items_cost.order_item_id 
AND order_meta_items_cost.meta_key = '_wc_cog_item_cost'

INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_meta_items_qty 
ON order_meta_items_qty.order_item_id = order_items_cost.order_item_id 
AND order_meta_items_qty.meta_key = '_qty'

WHERE  posts.ID = order_items.order_id
AND posts.post_status IN ('wc-completed')
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(posts.post_date, '+00:00', @@global.time_zone)) >= '1537747200'
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(posts.post_date, '+00:00', @@global.time_zone)) <= '1538351999'
```

**The results I want:**

- Have the right numbers of posts.ID (count_orders)
- Have the right total price of products (by the qty).

**In this example, it will be :**
Only the order 10 is completed, so we keep order_item_id 24 and 56.
Now, we want the price of the product by his quantity (qty of product in one order)

```
order_item_id 24 :
_product_cost = 79
_qty = 5
so 79*5 = 395

order_item_id 56 :
_product_cost = 99
qty = 3
so 99*3 = 297

** Right result in total_sales -> 395+297 = 692**
```

I've tried a lot of combinations, but I can't figure out how to do.

Do you have any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want the `COUNT( posts.ID )` to be 1 or 2 ?

Comment: The COUNT( posts.ID ) must be the number of orders. In this exemple, it's 1 because the order ID 11 is 'wc-suspend' ;)

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you the required total sales.

```
SELECT SUM(prod_meta_val) total_sales FROM
(SELECT order_item_id,  PRODUCT(meta_value) prod_meta_val 
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
WHERE meta_key IN ('_qty', '_product_cost')
AND order_item_id IN
(SELECT order_item_id FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items 
WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item' 
AND order_id IN
(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_status='wc-completed' 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(posts.post_date, '+00:00', @@global.time_zone)) >= '1537747200'
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(posts.post_date, '+00:00', @@global.time_zone)) <= '1538351999'
)
) GROUP BY order_item_id)
```

Comment: I have 3 problems with this syntax: 1/ it miss "LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = '685'".  2/ it miss also "count_orders" and 3/ I can't use PRODUCT() with my version of sql (mysql)